# Gradle task retry on failure

Tags: gradle, groovy, artifactory

This is the task which fails intermittently and when it is manually rerun then it usually passes, I want to retry this task 3 times programmatically with a 5 second delay between each retry until declaring it as a genuine failure:-

```
uploadWildFlyWar {
    dependsOn createAndCopySasJar
    description 'Uploads the Wild-fly war'
    group 'publishing'
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: repoProps["remoteRepoUrlVal"]) {
                authentication(userName: repoProps["remoteRepoUsernameVal"], password: repoProps["remoteRepoPasswordVal"])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Failure reason:-

> What went wrong:
> Execution failed for task ':commons:src:uploadWildFlyWar'.
> Could not publish configuration 'wildFlyWar'
> Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact common:wildfly-startup:war:Branch-8.8.3.5c8e849b5 from/to remote (https://artifactory.abc.com/artifactory/cprms-build-branch): Failed to transfer file: https://artifactory.abc.com/artifactory/cprms-build-branch/com/ideas/cpro/common/wildfly-startup/Branch-8.8.3.5c8e849b5/wildfly-startup-Branch-8.8.3.5c8e849b5.war.
> **Return code is: 502, ReasonPhrase: Bad Gateway.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are not after a "clean" solution, you can hack-around it like this:

```
// configure the uploadWildFlyWar task
uploadWildFlyWar { task ->
    // remember the original task actions, copying them to a new list as the  returned list is a live view
    def actions = [*task.actions]
    // replace the original task actions with one own task action that does the error handling
    task.actions = [{
        // remembered exceptions from first two runs
        def exceptions = []
        // try up to three times
        for (i in 1..3) {
            try {
                // execute the original actions
                actions.each { it.execute(task) }
                // if the original actions executed successfully, break the loop
                break
            } catch (e) {
                // on the third try if still throwing an exception
                if (i == 3) {
                    // add the first two exceptions as "suppressed" ones
                    exceptions.each { e.addSuppressed(it) }
                    // rethrow the exception
                    throw e
                } else {
                    // remember the first two exceptions
                    exceptions.add(e)
                    // wait 5 seconds before retrying
                    sleep 5000
                }
            }
        }
    } as Action]
}
```

Comment: Tried it but not working since the task tries to upload the war file during the configuration stage itself instead of execution stage. In my case the war file does not exist during the configuration stage hence it fails with:-
Could not publish configuration 'wildFlyWar'
   > Cannot publish artifact 'wildfly-startup.war' (C:\Programs\Jenkins\slave\workspace\cprms\commons\src\Proj_dist\dist\common_Branch-8.8.20.0ab47fd84\deployments\wildfly-startup.war) as it does not exist.

Comment: If the task tries to upload the file during its configuration stage, that is majorly bullshit then anyway and that task needs to be fixed. Executing the action at configuration stage makes absolutely no sense and just guarantees wrong behavior. You will for example upload stale war files from former runs if they are still there or get the error that it does not exist. So don't use that task as it is or you will regret it. The code I gave you works fine if the task behaves properly and does its task in its execution phase.

Comment: Can you explain your solution a bit, because it is not clear to me what your code has got to do with actually uploading the war file to the artifactory. My `uploadWildFlyWar` task looks totally different from your `uploadWildFlyWar` task.

Comment: Of course it looks different, my code just configures the existing task and works with any task that properly does its work at execution phase. I cannot guess how your task looks like or even what type it is. ;-)

Comment: I've added some code comments to the hack

Comment: Really a pity you were not able to accept the answer in time @parag-kadam, or at least award the bounty manually. Now half of the bounty is lost for good. >:-(